# Cannot connect to remote secure web socket server using python 3 websocket library

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, websocket, openssl

I have a secure web socket server implemented in python 3 running on a RaspberryPI device at address RASPI_ADDRESS, exposed on port 8000.
On the RaspberryPI device, this is what the ssl version is shown as:

```
>>> import ssl
>>> print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

For testing purposes, I am using a self signed certificate, generated with openssl: certificate file **cert.pem** with the companion private key in **key.pem**.

On the client side, I am on a Windows machine and I implemented the client as follows (the same cert.pem file from above is available here as a local copy):

```
import ssl
import websocket

ws = websocket.WebSocket(sslopt={"ssl_version": ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, "certfile": "cert.pem"})
try:
    ws.connect("wss://RASPI_ADDRESS:8000")
    ws.send("Hello, Server")
    print(ws.recv())
    ws.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: ", e)
```

I am getting this exception on ws.connect(...):

```
Exception:  [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4065)
```

(If I connect in a non-secure way using "ws://...", it works)

Unfortunately, I am not getting many relevant results when searching for this error. I have tried to also provide the private key in the sslopt as well ("keyfile": "key.pem"), but then the script seems caught in some sync blocking - no exception, nothing listed on the screen, but also nothing received on the server side.

Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `certfile` option is for the certificate in case of client certificates - in which case it would also need the private key. You are likely looking for the `ca_certs` option instead.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you, the idea sounds good! Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: If you still get the *exact* same error then the file is in the wrong format, i.e. it is not a PEM file or the line ends are wrong or similar. Hard to tell without having more information about the file than just its name. If you get a different error now then adjust your question to reflect what you are doing and what kind of error you get.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it was a case of Monday morning :-/ I am not getting the same error anymore; in fact, I am not getting any error at all, but I also don't see anything received on the server side. The script seems to be caught in the same sync blocking state I mentioned in my post when sending the key file as well.

Comment: Are you sure that the wss server is even working correctly, i.e. that it is a) really websocket and not plain socket and b) really wss and not ws? How did you test for this?

Comment: Yeah, I'm also beginning to suspect something might not be right there (not implemented by me). I'll have to do some more digging and see in the first place that a simple wss connection works for a dummy client/server pair locally. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved it by rewriting the server and client using the **websockets** library: https://pypi.org/project/websockets/

Perhaps it would also have run with the **websocket-client** library https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/ I was using before, but the docs were partly inconsistent and confusing. Writing here a simplified working solution for future reference, in the form of a dummy echo server.

**Server running on RasPI (visible in LAN at IP address RASPI_IP)**

```
import asyncio
import pathlib
import ssl
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"<<< {name}")

    greeting = f"Hello {name}!"

    await websocket.send(greeting)
    print(f">>> {greeting}")

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
localhost_pem = pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name("key_cert.pem")
ssl_context.load_cert_chain(localhost_pem)

async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(hello, "0.0.0.0", 8765, ssl=ssl_context):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

asyncio.run(main())
```

Note the "0.0.0.0" host IP in websockets.serve()! If we set this to "localhost", the client will see a stack trace ending with this error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 1225] The remote computer refused the network connection
```

**Client running on Windows machine:**

```
import asyncio
import pathlib
import ssl
import websockets

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
localhost_pem = pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name("key_cert.pem")
ssl_context.load_verify_locations(localhost_pem)
uri_linux = "wss://RASPI_IP:8765"

async def hello():
    uri = uri_linux
    async with websockets.connect(uri, ssl=ssl_context) as websocket:
        name = input("What's your name? ")

        await websocket.send(name)
        print(f">>> {name}")

        greeting = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"<<< {greeting}")

asyncio.run(hello())
```

This got me at least a reaction compared to the original implementation, as then I ran into this error:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: IP address mismatch, certificate is not valid for *RASPI_IP*. (_ssl.c:1129)
```

This is solved by generating a certificate with SAN instead of only CN: https://serverfault.com/a/880809
Additionally, I combined the certificate and the key into one file: `cat key.pem cert.pem > key_cert.pem`